Fixing interior Wall Cracks and Door Frame Gaps
I've recently relocated to a new place and I'm considering removing the current wallpaper in the living room and repainting it. However, upon removing the wallpaper, I noticed cracks in the wall about 5 mm wide and a significant gap between the door frame and the wall. I've attached photos for reference. I'm not very experienced with DIY projects, but I'm willing to give it a try. Any advice on how to fix the cracks in the wall and the gap by the door frame would be greatly appreciated.
WALL CRACK

**WALL VIEW 1

Door frame Gap


now you know why they used wallpaper

@Traveler I know, now I cannot cry, I am trying to find a way to fix

Two methods
Cosmetic and permanent
For cosmetic get a drywall filler (it comes in a tube for easy application).. It will cover the crack but not for long, it will come back eventually.
For more permanent repair get drywall mesh tape. It will hold the crack from cracking further.

Never heard of mesh tape keeping a crack from spreading.  A settling house—if that's what's casued the cracks—is way stronger than a little mesh.
